# Backup remote files with ssh|tar into archive.tar.gz

Tags: ssh, pipe, tar, scp

I am using the command `ssh user@remote -p 22 "tar cz my-folder" | tar xz -C /d/local-backups` to backup distant folders to my local drive.

It is working fine, and the folders structure is replicated as the same in my local drive. But instead of extracting the files and recreate the exact same folders structure, would it be possible to append the files into an archive ?

I tried something like `ssh user@remote -p 22 "tar cz my-folder" | tar rz -C /d/local-backups/arcive.tar.gz` but with no luck.

**Edit**
Here is the console output with the command

```
`ssh user@remote -p 22 "tar cz my-folder" | tar rvf -C /d/local-
backups/archive.tar.gz`

/d/local-backups/archive.tar.gz
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
/d/local-backups/archive.tar.gz
tar: Removing leading `/' from hard link targets
```

I also tried to create archive.tar.gz before (with a single text file inside) before running the command, but even if the archive exists, the files are not put into.

Is there a way to have only one file "archive.tar.gz" at the end containing all the files retrieved from my server?

Comment: "_but with no luck_" what happened? What error messages did you get? What did you think should have happened and what happened instead? What have you done to try and resolve the issue?

Comment: @roaima I have added some details. I am not a UNIX expert as what I looking for is perhaps not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By ideology of your command at the first step you creating an archive on remote machine

```
ssh user@remote -p 22 "tar cz my-folder"
```

and then extracting it on the local machine

```
| tar xz -C /d/local-backups
-C - change directory to "/local-backups" before performing an operation.
```

That is why by this command you theoretically can't have on the local machine an archive. But it much more simpler any way than extracting it. If you want just create an archive on the remote machine and save  an archive on the local machine you can just use

```
ssh user@remote -p 22 "tar cz my-folder" > /tmp/archive.tar.gz
```

This command gonna create an archive. After this you can check the results

```
$ tar -tvf archive.tar.gz
drwxr-xr-x zidercol/users    0 2021-12-20 18:10 Temp/
-rw-r--r-- zidercol/users  270 2021-12-20 18:10 Temp/T0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what if the server has not enough space to create the archive? Unfortunately, it is my case, it is why I am pulling data from the server instead of creating the archive on it.

Comment: I the proposed version you getting an archive by default. You don't have middle stage then data is uncompressed as in you example. Any way you should write where do you not have enough space - local or remote machine. Because on the remote machine you shouldn't have problems. Tar compressed archive wouldn't use any space on remote machine. If you have problems on local machine you should understand that the result ( archive.tar.gz ) is gonna be created without any middle stage which will use any additional storage.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If the archive is not created in the remote server and then transferred to the local folder, do I need a lot of memory to do this?